# SQL Server Trigger how to log all actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have some triggers which are used to duplicate data to another DB which have a different structure.

I need to do something like:

```sql
BEGIN TRY
if exists
UPDATE db2 set fld = INSERTED.fld

if not exists
INSERT INTO db2 ...
INSERT INTO log (text) values ('row inserted blabla'+:inserted.ID)

END TRY
TRY CATCH
INSERT INTO log (text) values ('insert failed blabla'+:ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH;
```

First, I used cursors because for each row I need to INSERT or UPDATE the 2nd DB and I'm using `TRY..CATCH` for errors. It's working but everyone's saying I should not use cursor for performance issues.

Second, I used dynamic SQL which write all my queries into a VARCHAR(MAX) which I execute after I passed on every records it's taking like 100 times.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL+ 'BEGIN TRY etc.....'+'END TRY'+'BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO  INSERT INTO log (text) values ('''insert failed blabla'''+:ERROR_MESSAGE()+')END CATCH;' 
FROM INSERTED
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

At first I was thinking about using a MERGE statement but my need is to track every records update or insert so the OUTPUT instruction is not enough because I need to logs stuff like the value of `@@IDENTITY`

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: [`@@identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) isn't your friend, especially when triggers are involved. Consider using an [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). It does provide access to `identity` column values. It also handles multiple rows.

Comment: Your replication doesn't account for deletes. I suggest that rather than cooking up all of these triggers that you use CDC https://bryteflow.com/sql-server-change-data-capture-cdc-for-real-time-sql-server-replication/#:~:text=SQL%20CDC%20is%20an%20integral%20part%20of%20SQL%20Server%20replication,-When%20data%20needs&text=Its%20primary%20function%20is%20to,Change%20Data%20Capture%20or%20CDC.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `OUTPUT` clause. From the documentation the OUTPUT works even if there is a rollback, so you might need more error checking. Here's a quick example from your pseudo code:

```
BEGIN TRY
  
if exists
BEGIN
  UPDATE db2 set fld = INSERTED.fld
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate  
        INTO @UpdateResults;

  INSERT INTO log(text)
  SELECT 'row updtaed blabla' + CAST(ID as nvarchar)
  FROM @UpdateResults;
END
if not exists
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO db2 ...
  OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate  
        INTO @InsertResults;

  INSERT INTO log(text)
  SELECT 'row inserted blabla' + CAST(ID as nvarchar)
  FROM @InsertResults;
END
  
END TRY
TRY CATCH
INSERT INTO log (text) values ('insert failed blabla'+:ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH;
```